# Prophet for hourly time series forecast

Tags: r, forecast, facebook-prophet

I'm currently testing the prophet package on an hourly time series (dataset from the M4 forecast competition [1]). Interestingly, this dataset doesn't contain any time stamp information (year/month/day/ hour) about the time series and only carries the raw observations. Since the prophet expects a data frame with ds (date type) and y (the time series), I had to synthetically generate a vector of timestamps to accommodate this scenario. Following is an excerpt of the code snippet:

```
ts <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2012-05-15 07:00"), length.out = 700, by = "hour")
history <- data.frame(ds = ts, y = time_series_data)
ts_fit <- prophet(history, daily.seasonality = TRUE,  weekly.seasonality = TRUE, yearly.seasonality = FALSE)
```

My question is whether synthetically generating such timestamps would affect the overall performance of the model ?. In other words, if I change the timestamp to a different one, `seq(from = as.POSIXct("2013-05-15 07:00"), length.out = 700, by = "hour")`, would this affect the forecast accuracy ?

And, also is this the correct way of handling the time series, in the absence of timestamp information ? or are there any other alternatives available? (in prophet)

Thanks,
Kasun.

[1] https://www.mcompetitions.unic.ac.cy/the-dataset/

Comment: I posted the same question on the prophet's Github page. Below [1] is the response I received from the developers. Seems to be the timestamp doesn't have any effect on the forecast, as long as you don't use the 'holiday' option.

[1] https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/864